# How can I make one flowfile the child of a separate pre-existing flowfile?

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi, amqp

When a flowfile comes into existence from an external source, but knows the uuid of an prior flowfile that it came from, how can I mark the existing flowfile as a parent of this one.

I see a number of ways I will encounter this, so I've intentionally tried to keep the question generic, but a specific case is:

A flowfile is sent to an external system via AMQP(PublishAMQP processor), which asynchronously performs work and reports back at some later point via AMQP(ConsumeAMQP processor).

FlowFile1: Processor -> AMQP(with FF1 uuid)

FlowFile2: AMQP(with FF1 uuid) -> Processor

Since the response has the uuid of the original flowfile, I would like to associate this response with the original flowfile

I do not see a way of doing this from the ProcessSession, FlowFile, ProvenanceEventRecord or anything else I have access to via bindings or otherwise. Most of my attempts have been through the ExecuteScript processor where I have access to the flowfile object and nifi dev api.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can only track the lineage from the time a flow file is created to when it leaves NiFi. Once it leaves NiFi then you are getting into cross-system lineage.